# android - How to update Fragment with SlidingMenu library

Tags: android, fragment, slidingmenu

I am using jfeinstein10's SlidingMenu library ([Click here !!!](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)).

In my ListFragment, I have an adapter with dynamic items.

But when I would like add item, and after, when I open my menu, this item is not display.

**Why ? How to update my ListFragment ?**

I debugged my application but another method in my ListFragment It'is never call when I open the menu.

**My BaseActivity**

```
public class BaseActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {


protected ListFragment mFrag;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    // set the Behind View
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
    FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    mFrag = MenuFragment.newInstance(100);
    t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
    t.commit();

    // customize the SlidingMenu
    SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);



}
```

}

**My Menufragment**

```
public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment {




public MenuFragment() {

}

public static final MenuFragment newInstance(int request) {


    MenuFragment f = new MenuFragment();
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle();

    bdl.putInt("my_request",request);
    f.setArguments(bdl);
    return f;
}


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(getActivity(),getArguments().getString("current"));
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setDividerHeight(0);


}
```